# Cannot query the value of property 'javaLauncher' because it has no value available

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

Hello Guys I am new to spring native.When I try `./gradlew compileNative` I get the error `* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':nativeCompile'.

> Cannot query the value of property 'javaLauncher' because it has no value available.`

I have installed graalvm and installed native-image and made the graalvm default on my machine.

[Here is the pastbin link to additional logs](https://pastebin.com/tuQ9nzqt).The bootBuildImage works fine.

I don't know whats wrong now.

OS:Arch Linux.

Comment: Please check that the environment variable JAVA_HOME has been set. Do a Google search if you are unsure of how to set the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guys the error was caused by an unset JAVA_HOME variable.I used to think that `archlinux-java set` does that for you by default.

Thanks *[Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2591131/eric)* for the info.